# apt-get install libphp-phpmailer not including class.phpmailer.php

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, php, apt-get

I am installing PHPMailer on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server. I ran the command `apt-get install libphp-phpmailer`. It installed the files under `usr/share/doc/libphp-phpmailer` as expected. However, it is missing the class file to require `class.phpmailer.php`.

I have tried running `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` to no avail.

How can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files I need are located at `usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer`. Not the `doc` folder.